# How to implement two levels of parallelism in java

Tags: java, algorithm, parallel-processing

I need to implement two levels of parallelism namely, component level and node level. As depicted in the following picture each component might contain several nodes where each node should be processed by a distinct thread. Assume that components are independent. Please advise me how to implement these two levels of parallelism in java programming language.

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you read up on threads and thread groups?

Comment: Yes, I know some java threads libraries like ExecutorService, Forkjoin and . . . What do you mean of thread groups?

Comment: I was refering to `java.lang.ThreadGroup`. From the JavaDoc: `The thread groups form a tree in which every thread group except the initial thread group has a parent.` - What you make of that is up to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have drawn looks to me like threads that are dispatching work to child threads.

There are many (at least four that I can think of) ways you could implement that using Java threads.

- Using plain threads which create / start / join child threads
- Using old-school thread pools to recycle the threads.
- Using Executors.
- Using the fork/join framework.

Without more information<sup>1</sup> on your problem, we can't advise on which would be better.  Or indeed how you would use threads at all.

I don't think that ThreadGroups are any help for this problem.

---

<sup>1 - They say that a picture is worth a thousands words ... but that's not true for all pictures.  Your diagram does not tell me anything about what your application does and how it is supposed to work.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The other information I can provide is that: I have a tree at which I am trying to process the nodes of each level in parallel. I have small number (maximum 32 nodes in each level) of coarse-grained nodes in each stratum. I think Forkjoin would not be a suitable solution (cz I think it is good for fine-grained but large number of nodes). Could you please provide me more details about other approaches (Executors or plain threads)? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: There is lots of detail in the Oracle Java Tutorials, and other places.  You don't need my help to read these.  The other salient point is that for a computationally intensive task, you won't get any more parallelism than you have physical cores / hyperthreads.